# Why won't PEAR work on my PHP Windows installation?

Tags: php, windows-7, cygwin, cmd, pear

I'm running Wampserver on Windows 7, and I can't seem to get PEAR to work. Well, that's 
not entirely true-apparently it works on the command line (both cmd.exe and on Cygwin).
Here's the sample program I found on PHP.Net that shows you if PEAR is installed:

```
<?PHP

require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));

?>
```

On the command line, it returns "bool(true)", and in the browser I get

```
Warning: require_once(System.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\foobar.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\foobar.php on line 3
```

I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong. It seems like both should work, but I'm stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Amanda, I assume PEAR is installed in `C:\PHP\PEAR`?  Do you have a PEAR sub directory under that?  I've seen a handful of installations where the default path, for some reason, was `C:\PHP\PEAR\PEAR`.

Comment: The only PHP directory I see on my system is C:\wamp\bin\php

Comment: Also, pear is in that directory, C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like your `include_path` is wrong.  Go change your PHP.ini and set your include path to:

```
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your apache (or other webserver) is picking up wrong php.ini.

- Make a page with a call to `phpinfo()`
- Load the page in browser
- Check the `PHP.ini` path its using.
- Copy your proper `php.ini` to that location.